# Disable weak Cipher ubuntu 16

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-16.04, cipher

I have started security scanning my network and have issues with Ubuntu 16 and weak cipher suites. I think I found the sshd config. but everything I read on the TLS for apache tells me to go to /etc/httpd which I do not have the directory. I see openssl ciphers but I can seem to figure out how to disable unwanted ciphers. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openssh` does not use TLS so ignore anything that talks about TLS. You will need to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. This [link](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html) may be somewhat dated but is interesting reading. My `sshd_config` has these lines for the MACs and ciphers

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
MACs hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
```

For web ciphers, edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl.conf`. I use

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

Comment: But what about the web ciphers?

Comment: @Brill My answer has been edited to reflect web configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I have to set a new answer

doneal24 made a small errata on the answer [above](https://serverfault.com/a/951779/477318), it is not

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl.conf

but rather

> /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf

the file to modify.

Cheers!

Comment: You should be able to suggest an edit to the answer.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider didn't know that you could edit the answer -subject to revision- while not being able to comment it! Just done so!

Comment: Great. I approved your edit, but it will be pending until one or two more people approve it. You will even get some reputation when it goes through.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Good! Should I delete this answer to reduce noise?